# How to get a slice of a VHDL unconstrained array?

Tags: arrays, vhdl

I'm trying to model a RAM chip in VHDL with generic parameters for the address and data bus widths and for the base address where the RAM is placed in the address space. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to get a slice of an generic unconstrained array parameter to compare it against a std_logic_vector signal.

This the reduced code that is intended to compute the "chip select" signal:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity e is
    generic (
        BASE_ADDR :std_logic_vector := x"C000";
        CELL_ADDR_WIDTH :integer := 4
    );
    port (
        address :in std_logic_vector (BASE_ADDR'length-1 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture behavioral of e is

    constant ADDR_WIDTH :integer := BASE_ADDR'length;

    signal cs :std_logic;

begin

    cs <= '1' when address(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) = BASE_ADDR(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) else '0';

end behavioral;
```

The Lattice ispLEVER VHDL compiler reports the following error:

```
23:64:23:110|Slice range direction does not match argument range
```

The message is caused by the expression `BASE_ADDR(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH)`.

How is a slice of the generic unconstrained array `BASE_ADDR` accessed correctly in VHDL?

Comment: Your unconstrained array defaults to a "to" range because the index type of std_logic_vector is integer and integer in turn is defined with a to range :). So use the to keyword in your slice.

Comment: You'll could also add an alias to your architecture declarative region - `alias BASEADDR: std_logic_vector(BASE_ADDR'LENGTH - 1 downto 0) is BASE_ADDR;` to define a direction and use that - `cs <= '1' when address(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) = BASEADDR(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) else '0';`

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions suggested by @Paebbels and @user1155120 resolve the VHDL compilation error. I quote the suggestions here with the code updated accordingly.

## @Paebbels: Use `to` in slice

> Your unconstrained array defaults to a "to" range because the index type of std_logic_vector is integer and integer in turn is defined with a to range :). So use the to keyword in your slice.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity e is
    generic (
        BASE_ADDR :std_logic_vector := x"C000";
        CELL_ADDR_WIDTH :integer := 4
    );
    port (
        address :in std_logic_vector (BASE_ADDR'length-1 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture behavioral of e is

    constant ADDR_WIDTH :integer := BASE_ADDR'length;

    signal cs :std_logic;

begin

    cs <= '1' when address(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) = BASE_ADDR(ADDR_WIDTH-1 to CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) else '0';

end behavioral;
```

## @user1155120: Declare an alias to define a direction

> You'll could also add an alias to your architecture declarative region - `alias BASEADDR: std_logic_vector(BASE_ADDR'LENGTH - 1 downto 0) is BASE_ADDR;` to define a direction and use that - `cs <= '1' when address(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) = BASEADDR(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) else '0';`

I used a more prominent name for the alias:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity e is
    generic (
        BASE_ADDR :std_logic_vector := x"C000";
        CELL_ADDR_WIDTH :integer := 4
    );
    port (
        address :in std_logic_vector (BASE_ADDR'length-1 downto 0)
    );
end;

architecture behavioral of e is

    constant ADDR_WIDTH :integer := BASE_ADDR'length;

    signal cs :std_logic;

    alias BASE_ADDR_ALIAS: std_logic_vector(BASE_ADDR'LENGTH - 1 downto 0) is BASE_ADDR;

begin

    cs <= '1' when address(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) = BASE_ADDR_ALIAS(ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto CELL_ADDR_WIDTH) else '0';

end behavioral;
```

Comment: There's no need to make aliases prominent.  An alias is an alternate name for a named entity (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.6 Alias declarations). They can be used for brevity as in selected names (8.3) as in implicitly declared aliases (6.6.3 Nonobject aliases) used for making enumeration names visible by the context of overload resolution (12.5).

Comment: I find names confusing that look very similar like `BASE_ADDR` and `BASEADDR`, therefore I thought I'd make the names more distinguishable in this code example. Of course your original suggestion is also technically correct.

Comment: If it's lack of confusion you're after considering simplifying the [design specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqAap.jpg).