# How to determine direction of a vector in VHDL (downto vs to)?

Tags: vhdl

I need to write a function that will shift data into an input vector. The input could be of type signed or unsigned. In order to make the function robust, I need to know the direction of the input vector i.e range declared using downto vs to. This information will be used to determine what index has the least significant bit.

How do I find out how the range has been declared and choose the correct least significant and most significant bit based on that information?

Comment: How do you envision the final architecture? At the end of the day your hardware can do one thing, so it's either little endian or big endian. Or do you mean that you want a if/else structure that uses the type of the signal to generate specific code? In the second case you won't have flexibility in the final design, but only pre-synthesis. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Fra93 This question is about VHDL mechanics, not hardware architectuire.

Comment: A possible duplicate of [How to get a slice of a VHDL unconstrained array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550829/how-to-get-a-slice-of-a-vhdl-unconstrained-array).

Comment: @Tricky yes exactly, so it's the second part of my question, to me it wasn't clear, but your answer is perfect :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array types have the default attributes `'ascending` and `'descending` which are both functions that return `true/false` depending on whether the range is actually `to` (ascending) or `downto` (descending). Hence, you will likely need to have the following coding style if you explicitly need to investigate the direction:

```vhdl
if p'ascending then
  -- do code for to direction
else
  -- do code for downto direction
end if;
```

Alternatively, you can use an `alias` to "normalise" the direction inside the function, which means an if/else is not needed depending on direction, as you know the direction inside the function:

```vhdl
function do_something( p : bit_vector ) return bit_vector is
  alias p_a  : bit_vector(p'length-1 downto 0) is p;    -- normalise p
  variable r : p_a'subtype;
begin
   -- use p_a as a downto vector
   
   return r;
end function;
```